# Invalid Scope: tagged_places in facebook api using php

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

I'm using facebook api in PHP. i tried to access the `tagged_places` details , it shows following error `Invalid Scope: tagged_places`
this is my code

`$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(
array(
'scope' => 'rsvp_event,sms,publish_actions,manage_pages,tagged_places,user_checkins'
));`

i have tried `user_tagged_places` instead of `tagged_places` , it clears my error but does not return result.
I have tried with following URL . it works fine 
`https://graph.facebook.com/431343680351802/tagged_places?access_token=my access token`.
but why when i call via application it does not work?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I have a found a way finally using Json parsing i retrieved data from 
`https://graph.facebook.com/userid/tagged_places?access_token=my access token`